# Flutter: Why widget is rebuilding more than 10 times when I use StreamProvider even when value not changes?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am watching a simple `StreamProvider` which just emits an int value. `MyWidget` is building only once if I am not assigning anything to `theme` variable but if I assign anything to `theme` then widget builds around 12 times.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final provider = ref.watch(streamProvider);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(foregroundColor: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("@@@@ build MyWidget");
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    );
  }
}

final streamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose(((ref) => Stream.value(1)));
```

This is printing `@@@@ build MyWidget` 12 times. If I do not read anything from `Theme.of` then it prints only once. What could be the issue here?

**Edit**

Everyone is saying it is the problem with `Theme.of(context)` but my confusion is why it is building only once if I convert `ref.watch` to `ref.read`?

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue with `Theme.of`, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89127 .

Comment: @Dimon It builds only once if I remove`ref.watch`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is not about Riverpod. You can remove any Riverpod dependencies and the problem will remain.

Also, I've narrowed down the problem a bit. Take a look at this code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('#build $MyApp');

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(elevation: 1),
        ),
      ),
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          print("#build Builder");

          Theme.of(context);

          return const SizedBox();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem appears whenever we define a new style in the line:

`style: TextButton.styleFrom(elevation: 1),`

If we write `TextButton.styleFrom()`, everything works as expected. Also, if we don't use `Theme.of(context)`, that's fine too.

It is probably necessary to open [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) :)

Answer (score 0):

It is combination of many things.

1. By making MyApp's build dependent on streamProvider, you are saying that every time there is a value from stream, rebuild the widget tree. (Remove ref.watch and you will have only one build)
2. Having Theme widget as decedent of MyApp and using Theme.of(context) inside MyWidget you are saying that whenever there is change in context, MyWidget should be rebuilt. (Remove Theme.of(context) while keeping ref.watch and you will have only 1 build)

Every time a event is emitted, there are other widgets (part of build function of MaterialApp which gets rebuilt. AnimatedTheme, AnimatedTheme and MyWidget were marked dirty by framework in this case. You can verify it yourself by adding `print('marking $this as dirty');` to flutter's framework.dart markNeedBuild method's end.

I think there is nothing wrong with either riverpod or flutter.

Comment: If you change `ref.watch` to `ref.read` it will print only once. That is what is confusing me. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Was running into this problem and it turned out to be a `Notifier` / `StreamProvider` listening to another `StreamProvider` and then the child not staying alive.

If you are using the generator add `@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)` instead of `@riverpod` to the child `StreamProvider`.

Otherwise add `ref.keepAlive();` inside the `StreamProvider`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered the use of ref.listen instead of ref.watch? with 'listen' you can compare the new emitted value with the old, and SetState only if there is a change...

Comment: That is not the question

Answer (score -1):

may stream is being re created or you try to assign value multiple times

Answer (score -2):

sure you can try

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    final CollectionReference myCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection');
    
    // Document reference for the document you want to delete
    final DocumentReference documentReference = myCollection.doc('documentId');
    
    // Call delete() on the DocumentReference to delete the document
    documentReference.delete();
```